# Leaflet meters to pixels per zoom level

Tags: leaflet

I'm creating an app using *Leaflet* library

I have a field `radius` that contains distance in meters (m).

```
const radius = 1000;
```

I would need to convert this field to pixels, but on different zoom levels

For zoom levels, I get values from `8` till `18`

I have this function that converts successfully on the current zoom level

```
function disToPixeldistance(distance){
  var l2 = L.GeometryUtil.destination(map.getCenter(),90,distance);
  var p1 = map.latLngToContainerPoint(map.getCenter())
  var p2 = map.latLngToContainerPoint(l2)
  return p1.distanceTo(p2)
}
```

But I would need to pass different `zoom levels` as an additional parameter and then convert them from meters to pixels

Like:

```
function disToPixeldistance(distance, zoomLevel)
```

Does anyone knows how could I achieve this ? Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `map.latlngToContainerPoint(latlng)` to `map.project(latlng,zoom)`

```
function disToPixeldistance(distance, zoom){
  zoom = zoom || map.getZoom();
  var l2 = L.GeometryUtil.destination(map.getCenter(),90,distance);
  var p1 = map.project(map.getCenter(), zoom)
  var p2 = map.project(l2,zoom)
  return p1.distanceTo(p2)
}
```